# How to stop an audio when PlayOneShot is used

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

So currently I have an audio clip that is 8 seconds long. However I want to be able to stop it from playing when specific things happen. Something like this:

```
private AudioSource soundPlayer2D;
private AudioClip sound;  

     void Start(){

     GameObject new2DsoundPlayer = new GameObject ("2DSoundPlayer");
     soundPlayer2D = new2DsoundPlayer.AddComponent<AudioSource> (); 
     new2DsoundPlayer.transform.parent = transform;

     }
     void Update() {

        if(shouldPlayAudio){

        soundPlayer2D.PlayOneShot (sound, fxVolumePercentage * allVolumePercentage);

        } else if(shouldStopAudio){

        //Stop Audio <--

        }
     }
```

Edit 1: Note I only want to stop the specific audio clip and not the Audio Source

Comment: [SoundPlayer2D.Stop()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Stop.html)? Also you should rename that property to `soundPlayer2D` to conform to standard naming conventions (only Class names start with an initial capital, or method calls on your property look like static references to a class).

Comment: but that would stop all audio being played by SoundPlayer2D would it not??, and then when I would want to play another sound on SoundPlayer2D the previous sound would then finish playing when I would resume SoundPlayer2D @Draco18s

Comment: whoops just a typo @Draco18s

Comment: I would argue that any clip that needs to be stopped shouldn't be played using `PlayOneShot()` and should have a separate AudioSource. (`AudioSource SoundPlayer2D;` still has a capital S)

Comment: oh, ok so you suggest I make a separate audio source to play this one specific sound... is there another alternative though?

Comment: No idea. I've never done something like what you're doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You **can't** stop Audio when `PlayOneShot` is used. It's like play and forget function. Of-course you can mute Unity's Audio System, but that's not a good solution.

You need to use the Play function instead. Simply assign the AudioClip to AudioSource then play it. It can now be stopped with the Stop function.

```
private AudioSource SoundPlayer2D;
private AudioClip sound;
```

Before playing, assign the AudioClip to the AudioSource

```
SoundPlayer2D.clip = sound;
```

Now, you can play it

```
SoundPlayer2D.Play();
```

And stop it:

```
SoundPlayer2D.Stop();
```

---

It's **never** a good idea to decide when to play an audio with a `boolean` variable. Don't do this because you will run into problems such as audio not playing because you are trying to play it multiple times in a frame.

You need to put that in a function that plays and stops the audio.

Something like this:

```
public void playMyAudio(AudioClip clipToPlay)
{
    SoundPlayer2D.clip = clipToPlay;
    SoundPlayer2D.Play();
}

public void stopMyAudio()
{
    SoundPlayer2D.Stop();
}
```

> and soundPlayer2D should solely be devoted to playing the sound
>   AudioClip?

Nope. You don't have to unless you need multiple audios to be playing at the-same time. You can always change AudioSource (`soundPlayer2D`) clip to another  `AudioClip` before playing it.

Comment: Yes I know I should not use a bool variable to determine when to play the audio , i was just using it as an example, but thanks regardless

Comment: Ok. Modified my answer to answer your first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the mute property on your audiosource.mute property to stop the incoming sound. It wont stop playing the clip but it will stop the sound of clip coming from your game.

in your case

soundPlayer2D.mute = true;